# NGINX not working for some users

Tags: nginx

I am serving a static site using NGINX. For most users the site appears fine, for some users, they are served the 'Welcome to nginx on Debian!' default page. They are using the same address `www.domain.co.uk` where domain is the real `domain` for the site.

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
}

http {

    server {
        listen 80;

            root /var/www/virtual/domain/;

            # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
            server_name www.domain.co.uk domain.co.uk www.domain.org.uk domain.org.uk;
            location / {
                index index.html index.htm;
            }
    }
    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile off;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

}
```

I haven't been able to replicate this issue at home or in my office on multiple devices. The DNS records haven't changed in at least a year or two.

I'm at a loss to why this might be happening, any help or suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does it occur on particular pages or just on the index page? Does it occur if they go to `www.domain.co.uk/index.html` rather than the bare domain?

Has the site only just been published? It could be overzealous caching by some providers.

Comment: Is this the only `server` block in your nginx configuration files?

Comment: @SimonGreenwood It has been like this for a while (>6 months). The static files that have been replaced are being served correctly (when they are served.) I am unable to replicate the issue so it's hard to test the `/index.html` idea but will try it. Thanks.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen Yes, this is my entire nginx configuration.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have Debians default server configuration enabled? Please check all files in `/etc/nginx` and its subdirectories.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen Yes, that seems to be it. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score -1):

Please try flushing the local DNS cache of the users experiencing the issue.

In Microsoft Windows, this can be done by "**ipconfig /flushdns**"

In Ubuntu 16.04, this can be done by "**sudo /etc/init.d/nscd restart**"